# The value entered in Select_list is not stored in Browser variable

Tags: ruby, watir

I am entering the value in select list through below code

```
b.select_list(:id,'something').select('hi how are you')
```

And yes it's choosing as expected and it appears in the select list, but the value which is entered has not actually stored in the browser variable behind screen, So the wrong page arrives due to the missing value in select_list, But when I choose manually,it happening and the right page arrives. How would I rectify this error?

Code on the page look like this,

> select  value="-1" origValue="-1"   tabindex="249" class="QuestionnaireSelect" name="nameid" id="2000007@2000064" style= ""
>   onkeypress="onComboKeyPress(this)"  onchange="closeAfterUnload = false"  onmousedown="onFocusFieldHandler(this)"   helpTextInfo=""  onblur="releaseCurrentFocusField()"  onclick="closeAfterUnload = false"

Comment: Can you give more details on how to reproduce the problem? In particular, can you give the HTML/Javascript that is required to see the problem.

Comment: hi, I have added one select box coding in the main post.

Comment: I can only assume that one of the events is not being raised. Without being able to reproduce the problem locally, it is hard to give a specific answer.